# How to get partnumber that have at least have one source type Website and at least one stockid equal 1 Based on PartNumber?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, stored-procedures, sql-server-2017, aggregate

I work on sql server 2017 i face issue i can't get `partnumber`

that have at least source type `website` and at least have `stockid` `equal 1` per `partnumber`

so with another meaning i need to get part numers that have `stockid` `1` and `source type` `website`

so i need to make select query get part numbers that must have source type `website` and stock `=1` Based on `Part number`

sample data

```
create table #stockyes
(
PartNumber varchar(100),
sourcetype varchar(100),
stockid tinyint
)
insert into #stockyes(PartNumber,sourcetype,stockid)
values
(1233,'Website',1),
(1233,'Website',0),
(1233,'Datasheet',1),

(8901,'Website',1),
(8901,'Website',0),

(9015,'Website',1),

(7801,'Website',1),
(7801,'Website',1),

(9401,'Datasheet',0),

(5688,'Datasheet',0),
(5688,'Datasheet',0),

(5688,'Lifecycle',2),
(5688,'Lifecycle',2),

(8409,'Lifecycle',1),

(6703,'Website',0),
(6703,'Website',0),
(6703,'Website',0),

(3099,'Website',0),
(3099,'Website',0),

(8541,'Website',0)
```

expected result

[image: expected result have website and stock id 1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be using exists:

```
select PartNumber,sourcetype,stockid
from #stockyes s
where exists ( select null 
               from #stockyes s1 
               where s.PartNumber=s1.PartNumber 
               and s1.sourcetype ='Website'
             )
and exists (  select null 
              from #stockyes s2 
              where s.PartNumber=s2.PartNumber 
              and s2.stockid =1
           );
```

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=e08aabf2b903fcaf92093e209180e7c0)

**EDIT** To get distinct partnumber only use:

```
select distinct PartNumber
from #stockyes s
where exists ( select null 
               from #stockyes s1 
               where s.PartNumber=s1.PartNumber 
               and s1.sourcetype ='Website'
             )
and exists (  select null 
              from #stockyes s2 
              where s.PartNumber=s2.PartNumber 
              and s2.stockid =1
           );
```

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=3ca1f48614a4a402b0f16fff57716f52)